# python enumerating a dictionary value object - does not work with large objects

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I load a json file into a dictonary in python, and then enumerate through the json key objects. I have the following code block :

```
    datelimit = datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1)       # limit date for completed_time
to_remove = []
dateformat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
for k, v in item_dict.items():                  # enumerate top_level objects
    for i, block in enumerate(v['completed']):  # enumerate inner blocks
        complete_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(   # skip last char from complete_time
            block["complete_time"][:-1], dateformat)
        # print(k, i, complete_time)              # uncomment for tests
        if complete_time < datelimit:           # too old
            to_remove.append((k, i))            # store the index for later processing

for k, i in reversed(to_remove):           # start from the end to keep consistent indices
    del item_dict[k]["completed"][i]
```

I notice that this seems to work fine for small json files (a few KBs) . But if the json file is really big (~3 MB) the code does not execute and it fails in the following line with the error :

```
for i, block in enumerate(v['completed']):  # enumerate inner blocks
    for i, block in enumerate(v['completed']):
KeyError: 'completed'
```

Any pointers on handling the larger json files ? what is the reason for the error ? thanks

Comment: The size of the file shouldn't be the issue - looks like your data just aren't consistent. 
 Try putting a check before your inner loop to see if `'completed'` is a key in `v`. In cases where that check fails, use print statements to figure out what's going wrong (ie what keys are in `v` on that iteration).

Comment: thanks andrew, yes I can see that a few of the blocks does not have a 'completed' or a 'complete_time' key. I think this is the issue. How do I best handle this ? check if it exists , and then perform the operation, else 'pass' ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  Just something like: `if "completed" not in v.keys(): print("Warning!  'completed' not found in keys of v")` ...`else: for i, block in enumerate(v['completed']):  # enumerate inner blocks...`  But whether you want to pass or not depends on what you're expecting to have happen with `to_remove` when `completed` isn't found.

Comment: hi andrew I have another question. When you say size of the file is not an issue, do you think this piece of code, can handle large json files ? (~100 MB) or should I be looking at breaking the json data into chunks ?

Comment: Depends on how much memory you have available.  But I'd recommend creating a new post if you run into a specific issue.  Good luck!